# java jsp web page caches POST request

Tags: java

I have *JSP* page with user registration form and add submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="action" value="add"/>
```

Form method is *POST*. My problem here is that when I fill form, push add - everything works - user is added, but when I press refresh page - the same *POST* request is sent, *PSQL exception* is thrown (dublicate users) and my application stops working (because I configured so). My question is how to disable such actitvity - meaning when I press refresh, I get empty page.

Comment: Implement [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: @kryger is right. You could use a <% response.sendRedirect("my.jsp") %> scriptlet in the landing page (after form submission) or in the servlet managing the POST, this should fix the problem.

Comment: Yes. You are all right. Proposed solution works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

As @kryger stated - [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) is the pattern for you.

The main idea is to redirect the browser after the POST to load next page with GET. That way, if the browser is refreshed / page is reloaded, this reload will happen on the GET - which is safe to do.

In JSP redirecting can be a bit tricky - if you don't have any Servlets or else in place you need to make sure that

```
response.sendRedirect("pagetoget.jsp"); 
return;
```

is called before response is committed (before any bytes are written). If you have JSP and JSP alone, you should do that by starting your jsp with <% and do that code right in the beginning.